# Getting Uncaught TypeError when attempting to randomly create data array

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" for the following and have not been able to find solution. The goal is to create a data array with random values for the x, y, width, and height of svg rects elements.

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="description" content="Drawing Shapes w/ D3 - " />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Drawing SVG Shapes with D3</title>
  <script src="d3.v3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <style>
    circle {
        stroke-width: 5;
        stroke:steelblue;
        fill:#888;
        fill-opacity: .5;
   }
         rect {
        stroke-width: 1;
        stroke:steelblue;
        fill:#888;
        fill-opacity: .5;
      }
            line {
        stroke: red;
        stroke-linecap: round;
        stroke-width: 5;
      }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script>

        function makeData(n){
          var arr = [];

          for (var i=0; i<n; i++){
            arr.push({
              x:Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1),
              y:Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1),
              width:Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1),
              height:Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1)
            })
          };

          return arr;
        }

        var data = makeData[2];

        var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width",200)
            .attr("height",200);

        svg.selectAll("rect")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
            .attr("width", function(d) { return d.width; })
            .attr("height", function(d) { return d.height; });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It originally worked when I had a static data array but now does not when attempting to create the same data object from randomly generated values. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error in the function call. A function is called with parenthesis not square brackets:

```
var data = makeData(2); // not makeData[2]
```

If you meant to extract elements from the array returned by the function, use this:

```
var data = makeData(2);
var data1 = data[0];
var data2 = data[1];
```